# PyInstaller - Too Large File Size with easyOcr

Tags: python, pyinstaller, easyocr

I am using PyInstaller to create an executable file for my project. The project uses `opencv` and `pywin32`. The file size is 54MB, and after installing easyocr, the size is about 323MB.

I run `pyinstaller --onefile .\main.py --paths C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages --key myKey -n fileName` to create an executable file.

Is there way to reduce the file size? Is this expected? Is there something I can do?

[image: File size comparison]

Logs:

```
213 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.10.1
213 INFO: Python: 3.9.0
213 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
233 INFO: UPX is available.
236 DEPRECATION: Bytecode encryption will be removed in PyInstaller v6. Please remove cipher and block_cipher parameters from your spec file to avoid breakages on upgrade. For the rationale/alternatives see https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/6999
243 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\undefined\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject',
 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages']
688 INFO: Will encrypt Python bytecode with provided cipher key
688 INFO: checking Analysis
865 INFO: Building because C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py changed
865 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
874 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
884 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1610 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
1848 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2748 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4450 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4561 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4567 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
4607 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py
4724 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
5161 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
6149 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6401 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6528 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7158 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7340 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7780 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
8778 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pynput.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
9076 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
9177 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-easyocr.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
9226 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9277 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9771 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9816 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9866 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torch.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
9876 INFO: hook-torch: raising recursion limit to 5000
10453 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19550 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
19935 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
20087 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
22206 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26093 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
26919 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
34869 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
35412 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
35659 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
36181 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37343 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torchvision.ops.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
39484 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was importe
d before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
39914 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
39934 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
39996 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
40201 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
40804 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
40884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
40884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
41051 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
44332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-skimage.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
44761 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-skimage.data.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
46728 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-skimage.io.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
49115 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shapely.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
49400 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'tinyaes'
49400 INFO: Processing module hooks...
49400 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-easyocr.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
49752 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-imageio.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
51026 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51498 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51498 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51509 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51529 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51702 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
51702 INFO: checking Tree
51752 INFO: checking Tree
51772 INFO: checking Tree
52406 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
52457 WARNING: Ignoring /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 imported from C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\torch\_inductor\codecache.py - only basenames are supported with ctypes imports!
52488 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
52502 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
52508 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
52508 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
52518 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
52528 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
52534 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pywintypes.py'
52538 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pythoncom.py'
52538 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_setuptools.py'
52549 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
52692 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was importe
d before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:177: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datapoints\__init__.py:12: UserWarning: The torchvision.
datapoints and torchvision.transforms.v2 namespaces are still Beta. While we do not expect major breaking changes, some APIs may still change ac
cording to user feedback. Please submit any feedback you may have in this issue: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/6753, and you can also
 check out https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/7319 to learn more about the APIs that we suspect might involve future changes. You can silence this warning by calling torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning().
  warnings.warn(_BETA_TRANSFORMS_WARNING)
C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\v2\__init__.py:54: UserWarning: The torchvisi
on.datapoints and torchvision.transforms.v2 namespaces are still Beta. While we do not expect major breaking changes, some APIs may still change
 according to user feedback. Please submit any feedback you may have in this issue: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/6753, and you can a
lso check out https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/7319 to learn more about the APIs that we suspect might involve future changes. You can silence this warning by calling torchvision.disable_beta_transforms_warning().
  warnings.warn(_BETA_TRANSFORMS_WARNING)
5296 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): ['C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-package
s\\numpy\\.libs', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\App
Data\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\li
b\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'C:\\Users\
\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Pytho
n\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\../../x64/vc14/bin', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\.libs', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\shapely.libs']
5296 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\../
../x64/vc14/bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:
\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common', 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA Nv
DLISR', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\
\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS', 'C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\
undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\S
ystem32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common', 'C:\\Prog
ram Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS', 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR', 'C:\\upx']     
60277 INFO: Looking for eggs
60277 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.dll
60277 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
60297 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\build\pythonProject\warn-pythonProject.txt
60540 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\build\pythonProject\xref-pythonProject.html
60789 INFO: checking PYZ
60881 INFO: checking PKG
61012 INFO: Building because toc changed
61012 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) fileName.pkg
162425 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) fileName.pkg completed successfully.
162624 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\undefined\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
162624 INFO: checking EXE
162778 INFO: Building because toc changed
162778 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
162778 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dist\fileName.exe.notanexecutable
162811 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
162821 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\undefined\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
162831 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
162841 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
162841 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
162841 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
162841 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\undefined\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dist\fileName.exe.notanexecutable
162861 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
162861 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
162972 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
163710 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is this "piece of code" posted here for? how it is relevant?

Comment: I was asked to `include a minimal reproducible example so that readers can run your code to answer your question.`.

Comment: i am still not convinced this snipped helps reproduce anything related to your question. Any logs from pyinstaller during building to share?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I removed the code and added the logs.